# Duplicate file for APK using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, build, duplicates

I have an Android app `App` which references an Android library `AndLib`.
Both of them have some native code which links with OpenCV native library.

At first, I compiled the native code of `App` and `AndLib` by linking statically with OpenCV but it resulted in a huge .apk file since the OpenCV library is present twice.

Then I tried to compile the native code by linking OpenCV as a shared library.
In the `libs` folder of `App`, I have two .so libs : `libapp.so`and `libopencv-java.so`.
In the `libs` folder of `AndLib`, I have two .so libs : `libandlib.so`and `libopencv-java.so`.

And when I try to build the .apk of `App`, I get this error :

```
Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv-java.so
Origin 1: C:\workspace\android_body\App\libs\armeabi-v7a\libopencv-java.so
Origin 2: C:\workspace\android_body\AndLib\libs\armeabi-v7a\libopencv-java.so
```

Is there any way to solve my issue?

Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just compile the AndLib first and only then compile your App project?

Comment: Yes, I compile them separately. And I have this error when compiling the App.